# AWS Sagemaker ClientError: imread read blank (None) image for file: /opt/ml/input/data/train/image_directory/key_of_first_image.jpg

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/imageclassification_caltech/Image-classification-lst-format.ipynb) on my own dataset, which is on S3 - both image files and .lst files.
The structure of the S3-bucket is:

```
s3://{bucket_name}/image-classification/train -> in here I have 2 'directories' with images of my 2 classes

s3://{bucket_name}/image-classification/train_lst

s3://{bucket_name}/image-classification/validation -> in here I have 2 'directories' with images of my 2 classes

s3://{bucket_name}/image-classification/validation_lst
```

I have setup the IAM-role for Sagemaker to have access to the bucket, the bucket has 'sagemaker' in it's name.
When I finally run the script (almost identically as in the tutorial, I only need a session with a profile_name to access Sagemaker), it gives me the error above and ends with a failed job status. I can't find any solution on this. All idea's are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you make it to work? If so, what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the code is almost identical to the tutorial, it's possible; it's due to the image files.

Try checking the integrity of the JPG file compression and channels.

For some reason, imread is reading a channel which is "blank"/(empty) on your file(s).

Edit:


If, after review, the format images are fine, try checking the path on the `*.lst` files: `(train_lst and validation_lst)`, wrong paths pointing to unexistent data usually result in such errors.

Comment: I have restarted the tutorial by using the dataset in the tutorial instead of my own to make sure the images are correct, not too big, etc...
The path to the first image is: 
`s3://<my_bucket_name>/image-classification/train/237.vcr/237_0070.jpg`
The first item of the train_lst (where the error occurs) is:
`14204 236.000000 237.vcr\237_0070.jpg`
s3train channel points to: 
`s3://{}/image-classification/train/'.format(bucket)`
So this should be working, but still gives the same error.

Comment: @JanoRoelandt How did you resolve it? I am getting the same error...

Comment: I worked with RecordIO format instead of Image format, I couldn't figure out the Image format unfortunately. Info on the RecordIO format training with Sagemaker can be found here: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/image-classification.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try verifying the `*.lst` file path and please follow the instructions as mentioned here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/image-classification.html

For example, if your training images are stored in `s3://<your_bucket>/train/class_dog`, `s3://<your_bucket>/train/class_cat`, and so on, specify the path for your train channel as `s3://<your_bucket>/train`, which is the top-level directory for your data.

In the `.lst` file, specify the relative path for an individual file named `train_image_dog1.jpg` in the `class_dog` class directory as `class_dog/train_image_dog1.jpg`.

You can also store all your image files under one sub-directory inside the `train` directory. In that case, use that sub-directory for the relative path. For example, `s3://<your_bucket>/train/your_image_directory`.